# Can I import a function dynamically from different .py files based a condition through command "from <root.fold1.fold2.{dynamic name}> import module"

Tags: python, dynamic, import, dynamic-import, loadmodule

Scenario:
I have a function which is going to instantiated in different test_.py files

```
EX: 
test_name1.py
test_name2.py
test_name3.py
```

instance name is tools.py and will be created in with same name in all of the above test files.

now I would need to import this instance in another file (Ex: utils.py).
For ex, if I run the test_name1.py, instance from this file should get imported to utils.py and
if I run the test_name2.py, instance from this file should get imported to utils.py. like this

I want to achieve some thing like

```py
test_file == "test_name1.py":
from root.fold1.fold2.{test_file} import tools
```

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: `import_module('..root.fold1.fold2.{%s}' % test_file, 'tools')`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module